# How to add a single meta tag conditionally in vue-cli (webpack build) to index.html

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I want to add this above tag in index.html for SIT/sandbox environment, how can I do this?

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

I can't have an access `process.env` variables in index.html file, so that's why I am unable to do this.

**EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION:**

Is there any way to adapt the vue-cli (webpack) build process to add one specific `<meta>` tag to the `index.html` conditionally depending on the build profile? The `<meta>` tag should be appended during the build process, not on runtime with browser JavaScript.

Comment: Do you want to conditionally add it to your index.html? During the build process or dynamically with JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, I want to add above-mentioned tag as conditionally.

Comment: You did not answer my second question.

Comment: sorry, if both options works, please tell me both.

Comment: I think dynamically with JS mean we can check if specific domain then adds above code, but @ssc-hrep3 how can with the build process please.

Comment: What build process do you have? Webpack, browserify, grunt, gulp, some else tool, nothing or something self-created? You need to give some information about your setup.

Comment: I am using built-in vuejs build process, Webpack. Nothing doing anything special in it.

Comment: I've edited your question and nominated it for reopening.

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of:

- Webpack and Vue-Cli environment variables
- Lodash in the public/index.html which vue-cli uses as a template

So your `public/index.html` would have a lodash instruction where the robots content is:

```
<meta name="robots" content="<%= process.env.ROBOTS_META%>"/>
```

Then make a new file in the root of your project called `.env` which contains the text:

```
NODE_ENV=production
ROBOTS_META=
```

Then make a second file in the root of your project called `.env.dev` containing:

```
NODE_ENV=production
ROBOTS_META=noindex,nofollow
```

If you want your production build, run: `vue-cli-service build` and the `.env` is used

For your dev/test/staging environments, run: `vue-cli-service build --mode dev` and the `.env.dev` is used.

To read more about VueCli environment variables see here:
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables